# Proper way to fill list row with custom image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am facing some minor issue with adjusting the size of a custom image to fill the list row completely.

[image: screenshot]

Image with scale effect:

[image: screenshot2]

In the screenshot it can be seen that it is being clipped. The only way how I found I could cheat this is to use `.scaleEffect(1.13)` which is not ideal, as I have to find and tweak the number to fill the empty space.

I tried many other options I found online, but without luck. All the commented code lines did not work.

```
.background(
    displayImageView(for: post)
    //.scaleEffect(1.13)
    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    //.scaledToFill()
    //.scaledToFit() 
    .opacity(0.4)
            )
            //.cornerRadius(10)
            //.clipped()
        }
    }
```

What would be the proper way to fill it automatically?

Code:

```
struct PostView: View {
    var post: test2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                // Display Image (100x100)
                displayImageView(for: post)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.leading, -8)

                // Profile Picture, Username, and Caption
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    HStack {
                        // other image code ...
                        Spacer()
                        //DateTimeView(timestamp: post.timestamp)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(
                displayImageView(for: post)
                    //.scaleEffect(1.13)
                    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    //.scaledToFill()
                    //.scaledToFit() // This will scale the image to fit the space without cropping
                    //.blur(radius: 3)
                    .opacity(0.4)
            )
            //.cornerRadius(10)
            //.clipped()
        }
    }


    @ViewBuilder
    private func displayImageView(for post: test2) -> some View {
        if let imageName = post.localDisplayImagePath {
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let imagePath = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(imageName).path
            
            if let imagePath = imagePath, let displayImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
                Image(uiImage: displayImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            } else if let displayUrl = post.displayUrl {
                URLImageView(url: displayUrl, isCircle: false, size: 100)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
            }
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is being clipped? I don't see anything wrong with the screenshot. Can you also show a screenshot with `.scaleEffect(1.13)` (presumably, that is your desired output)?

Comment: added second screenshot, you can see the scale effect fills up the list row, in the first screen its not fully covered. @Sweeper

Comment: You mean the image shouldn't be sticking out on the left? Is `PostView` a list row? If so, you should apply `.listRowBackground(displayImageView(for: post))` on `PostView`, instead of `background`.

Comment: My goal is to fill the whole list row as you ca see in the second screen without the need using `.scaleEffect()` as using scale effect isn't ideal for this setup. @Sweeper

Comment: Does `listRowBackground` work? If not, you need to show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the issue. This means you should also include the image (or a URL to it) you are using.

Comment: it does work indeed, i am just trying figured out why its only working in my second list view and not in Pending list view. but it does apply the background properly @Sweeper

Comment: As I said, you need to show a [mcve]. Note that nothing happens if you put `listRowBackground` on a view that is not a list row. Putting it on a `Text` that is inside a `VStack` that is inside a `List` will not work, for example. You'd need to put it on the `VStack`.

Comment: I figured it out, had to tweak it in my contentview. This solved my issue, so thank you @Sweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `PostView` is the row of a `List`, you can use [`listRowBackground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listrowbackground(_:)), instead of `background`.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
    // ...
}
// note that this should be applied to the "outermost" view.
// in your code, it's the VStack, not the HStack
.listRowBackground(displayImageView(for: post).opacity(0.4))
```